# Dynamically Removing Element from menu according to screen size

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

The other day I saw on a website it had several tabs A|B|C|D|E|MORE now as soon as you zoom in desktop browser it changes to A|B|C|MORE and then further zooming changes it to A|MORE and vice versa on zooming out.
I'm populating my menu using AngularJS so I was wondering how to write a directive for that?

Comment: do you remember that site address? i am sure they are using plugin which can be tracked..

Comment: Do you really mean zoom (`ctrl` + `scroll` or `+`/`-`) or resizing the window?

Comment: I meant ctrl + scroll or +/-

Comment: instacart.com uses this functionality

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using CSS and Mediaqueries for that. Actually this can be done in CSS only.

### Mediaqueries

Mediaqueries are rules that "activate" CSS selectors and theire style definitions upon device/screen attributes. Among others: mediatype, screen width/height, device width/height, resolution (pixel per inch), device pixel ratio, orientation, ...

Details:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Queries

### My solution

- My solution uses flex-box to extend the column of primarily visible buttons to the full available width where as the "More..." button is floating right and being fixed width.
- When the decreasing width "triggers" a breakpoint, the mediaquery will match, hiding the primary buttons and showing the buttons within the submenu.
- The submenu opens on `:hover`, no Javascript required.

[JsFiddle Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/aagdC/4/)

(Should work in all modern Browsers, including IE 11, tested only in Chrome ~33, FF ~27)

### Details

#### Flex

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="primary">
        ...
    </ul>
    <div class="more">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    display: flex;
    ...
}

#menu .primary {
    margin: 0 50px 0 0;
    flex: 1;
}
```

#### Mediaqueries

```
/* hide the buttons that are visibile in the primary menu */
#menu .more li:nth-child(1), 
#menu .more li:nth-child(2), 
#menu .more li:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}

/* 1st breakpoint: hide primary button, show the correstponding one in the submenu */
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    #menu .primary li:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu .more li:nth-child(3) {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* 2nd breakpoint: ... and so on ... */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #menu .primary li:nth-child(2) { /* the same procedure ... */ }
    #menu .more li:nth-child(2), 
    #menu .more li:nth-child(3) { /* the same procedure ... */ }
}
```

---

### Full code

#### HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="primary">
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>BBB</li>
        <li>CCC</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="more">
        More...
        <ul>
            <li>AAA</li>
            <li>BBB</li>
            <li>CCC</li>
            <li>DDD</li>
            <li>EEE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* Make the children elements flex */
#menu {
    display: flex;
    height: 30px;
}

#menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

/* The button wraper will flex to full remaining width */
#menu .primary {
    margin: 0 50px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    flex: 1;
}

#menu .primary li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    min-width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Place the "more..." button right */
#menu .more {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

/* Hide hoverable submenu by default */
#menu .more ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Show on hover */
#menu .more:hover ul {
    display: block;
}


/* Hidden by default, reactivated by the following Mediaqueries */

#menu .more li:nth-child(1), 
#menu .more li:nth-child(2), 
#menu .more li:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    #menu .primary li:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu .more li:nth-child(3) {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #menu .primary li:nth-child(2) {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu .more li:nth-child(2), #menu .more li:nth-child(3) {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aagdC/4/)

Comment: hey there...thank you for such an explicit response but I think viewing your solution I devised my own jus lacking the proper DOM selection

Comment: <div id="menu">
    <ul class="primary">
        <li>AAA</li>
        <li>BBB</li>
        <li>CCC</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="more">
        More...
        <ul>
            <li>AAA</li>
            <li>BBB</li>
            <li>CCC</li>
            <li>DDD</li>
            <li>EEE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: <ul class="primary">
        <li>AAA
        <li>BBB
        <li class="hide">CCC            <li class="hide">DDD
            <li class="hide">EEE
    </ul>
    <div class="more">
        More...
        <ul>
            <li>CCC
            <li>DDD
            <li>EEE
</ul></div>

 now using the juery window resize and binding it to a set of hide and show classes  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).bind("resize", function(){
   $( "body" ).prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + "</div>" );
   $(".primary>li").removeClass('hide');
   $(".more>li").addClass('hide');
  });
});

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using Bootstrap 3. As long as you don't intend to just primarily use Javascript, Bootstrap3's `.hidden-xs, .hidden-sm, .hidden-md, .hidden-lg` should suffice.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Shown 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shown 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Show 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-xs xs"><a href="#">Hidden XS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-sm sm"><a href="#">Hidden SM</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-md md"><a href="#">Hidden MD</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-lg lg"><a href="#">Hidden LG</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLxXz/

Comment: Actually I'm using Bootstrap but "try-catch-finally"'s fiddle is somewhat close to what I require but its too messy, Your fiddle isnt what i'm trying to ask, please help

Answer (score 0):

Ok this goes long way to the Update of Bootstrap 3.1.1 from 3.0 by the introduction of "hidden-xs,visible-lg" classes.
Now all I did was create a new object class:"hidden-sm hiddem-xs" and ask my ng-class="{{item.class}} in AngularJS to fetch and add class dynamically which solves the problem by setting different classes accordingly for different menu items.